# How to handle python library not accepting a newline?

Tags: python, lambda, nlp

I'm a relatively new developer finishing up a final project for school, so forgive me if this issue is obvious.

Attempting to run a lambda on a csv file to run some NLP on a database of recipes, more specifically their ingredients required. Here is the function being run through the lambda.

```
def ingredient_cleanup(ingredientList):
    
    terms_to_remove = ['salt', 'pepper', 'oil','of', 'zest','rind','fresh', 'butter', 'sugar', 'water', 'cloves', 'all','purpose', 'black', 'pepper', 'garlic', 'powder', 'cinnamon', 'juice', 'paprika','clove', 'chili','ground','extra','virgin','granulated','cumin','dried','oregano', 'kosher', 'boneless','skinless','canola', 'basil', 'white','thyme','cilantro','vinegar','powder','confectioners','seasoning','lean','curry','light','crushed','dry','boiling','sea']
    
    # turn ingredients from objects into a list
    if isinstance(ingredientList, list):
        ingredients = ingredientList
    else:
        ingredients = ast.literal_eval(ingredientList)
    
    # initialize lemmatizer and ingredient list to be returned
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    cleaned_ingredients = []
    
    for i in ingredients:
        # Split words according to spaces and hyphens
        items = re.split(' |-', i)
        
        # Remove any non-alphabetic terms, set it lower-case and remove any accents
        items = [word for word in items if word.isalpha()]
        items = [word.lower() for word in items]
        items = [unidecode.unidecode(word) for word in items]
    
        # Lemmatize each word for analysis and comparison
        items =[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in items]
        # remove common terms ingredients listed in terms_to_remove
        items = [word for word in items if word not in terms_to_remove]
        
        if items:
            cleaned_ingredients.append(' '.join(items))
    cleaned_ingredients_str = ' '.join(cleaned_ingredients)
    return cleaned_ingredients_str

df['RecipeIngredientParts'] = df['RecipeIngredientParts'].apply(lambda x: ingredient_cleanup(x))
```

Upon running I get the following error:

```
Cell In[8], line 1 in <lambda>
df['RecipeIngredientParts'] = df['RecipeIngredientParts'].apply(lambda x: ingredient_cleanup(x))

Cell In[3], line 9 in ingredient_cleanup
ingredients = ast.literal_eval(ingredientList)

File ~anaconda3libast.py:64 in literal_eval
node_or_string = parse(node_or_string.lstrip(" t"), mode='eval')

File ~anaconda3libast.py:50 in parse
return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,

File <unknown>:1
character(0
^
SyntaxError: '(' was never closed
```

After digging into the library it seems there is a newline in the return statement that the interpreter doesn't know how to handle. I'm nervous to simply backspace it away, I know that's generally a bad idea ha. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Please post your code, not just the error messge.

Comment: Basically, it looks like you forgot the `)` to end a function call.

Comment: @Barmar done, though the issue doesn't seem to be within my function based on the error message. It appears to be rooted in the library related to the ast.eval() function

Comment: The problem is that there's a syntax error in one or more of the `df['ingredientList']` values.

Comment: So one of them has an unmatched parenthesis.

Comment: If you're having trouble finding it, try a divide-and-conquer approach. Split the CSV file in half, and run the script on each half. When you get the error, split that file in half and try again. Eventually you'll find the line that's causing the error.

Comment: You could also just write a simple `for` loop that iterates over the rows of the df. Print the line number, then call `ast.literal_eval(row['ingredientList'])`. When it gets the error, you'll see the line number before the error message.